# Converting a hex number to a color value

Tags: colors, hex

I have an LCD firmware that I'm trying to modify by adding a few more colors. I found the color definitions as below,

```
#define WHITE                 0xFFFF
#define BLACK                 0x0000
#define BLUE                  0x001F
#define GBLUE                 0X07FF
#define RED                   0xF800
#define MAGENTA               0xF81F
#define GREEN                 0x07E0
#define CYAN                  0x7FFF
#define YELLOW                0xFFE0
#define BROWN                 0XBC40
#define BRRED                 0XFC07
#define GRAY                  0X8430
```

How do these values translate to actual hex color values? For example, cyan is listed as `0x7FFF` but the hex color value of Cyan is `#00FFFF`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is RGB565 colour format. 5 bits for red, 6 bits for green, 5 bits for blue.

```
WORD red_mask = 0xF800;
WORD green_mask = 0x7E0;
WORD blue_mask = 0x1F;
BYTE red_value = (pixel & red_mask) >> 11;
BYTE green_value = (pixel & green_mask) >> 5;
BYTE blue_value = (pixel & blue_mask);
```

And the other way:

```
// Assuming the color values have been truncated to the correct number of bits:
WORD pixel565 = (red_value << 11) | (green_value << 5) | blue_value;
```

Ref:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/working-with-16-bit-rgb